# How to enable the debugger for Laravel 10 project hosted using Laradock 3

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, xdebug, laravel-10, laradock

I have been trying to understand a way to enable debugger in my Laravel project using the Xdebug.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA IDE and I have enabled `PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG` and `WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG` but, I'm stuck understanding how to configure my IDE and listen to a specific debug port so that whenever an API call is made, I can debug my code. I prefer to use IntelliJ IDEA over PhpStorm.

I couldn't find any useful blogs or documentation so far. Any steps or blogs regarding the steps to configure debugger will be much appreciated.

Comment: *"I'm stuck understanding how to configure my IDE and listen to a specific debug port"* Xdebug in PhpStorm (or IntelliJ IDEA with PHP plugin) will listen on 9000 and 9003 ports by default (default ports used by Xdebug v2 and v3). Ports are set at `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Debug` (that's for PhpStorm, in IntelliJ it might be a bit different path). All the docs in IntelliJ for PHP are referring to PhpStorm docs anyway: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debug.html

Comment: *"so that whenever an API call is made, I can debug my code"* I suggest you look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html P.S. Having `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` in your php.ini will instruct Xdebug to try to debug every single request regardless if "debug me" flag (a cookie/request param/env variable) is present (easier to start with if you do not have much prior experience of debugging/settings up the Xdebug).

Comment: I don't have any helpful links specific for Laradoc though (that may cover nuances specific to Laradoc), only general help pages: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ . The rest is just debugging PHP that is running in a Docker container. You start with checking your actual Xdebug config -- see the output of `xdebug_info()` in the environment that you want to debug (a CLI / Web page / API call).

Comment: There are soooo many blog articles about "docker phpstorm xdebug" that it's at least 2 pages of Google search results. https://dev.to/jackmiras/xdebug-in-phpstorm-with-docker-2al8 the best I took from those results is: fill the `IDE_KEY` in your Laradock `.env` file. And map your local directory to the directory in your Docker workspace container (one of the steps setting up 'server'